# How to make a click game like the example

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering where I would begin to create a game like this: http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/

Essentially just click, tally up clicks, buy things which auto put up your clicks. What languages would I need to know for this? And what references/tutorials there may already be for this type of thing?

Also, currently I know HTML/CSS and Javascript (A little bit).

Comment: Go to http://www.codecademy.com/ and learn some JS. You'll progress up to building such games while you learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add up clicks globally (so if you click 5 times and someone else clicks 5 times it shows up as 10) I would suggest learning php, because you could use it to write the number of clicks to a file on the server or through a database. If you just want the individual user's clicks for the individual session, javascript should be fine. Create an  tag and inside it put the cookie image. for the href attribute, put "javascript:" and then the name of the function that increments your counter.

example:

```
//JS
var clicks = 0;
function count () {
  clicks ++;
}
function disp () {
  //display clicks somehow
}
<!--HTML-->
<a href="javascript:count()"><img src="cookie.jpg" /></a>
```